# Query to replace a column values with the first row of that column for remaining rows for each group

Tags: sql, oracle

Data is as below in the table.

```
brnach_id  branch_loc branch_name
1222         HYD        COMPUTER
1222         HYD        NULL
1222         HYD        COMPUTER
1222         HYD        NULL
1222         HYD        NULL
1333         BLR        ENGINEERING
1333         HYD        NULL
1333         BLR        NULL
1333         CHI        NULL
1444         PUN        MARKETING
1444         HYD        NULL
```

For each branch_id I want to replace the branch_name column values with the first row for remaining rows.

The expected output is

```
brnach_id  branch_loc branch_name
1222         HYD        COMPUTER
1222         HYD        COMPUTER
1222         HYD        COMPUTER
1222         HYD        COMPUTER
1222         HYD        COMPUTER
1333         BLR        ENGINEERING
1333         HYD        ENGINEERING
1333         BLR        ENGINEERING
1333         CHI        ENGINEERING
1444         PUN        MARKETING
1444         HYD        MARKETING
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL (not just Oracle SQL), result sets are unordered unless you specify an `ORDER BY` clause to give them an order. In your case, there is nothing obvious that would determine what makes one row the "first" row.

Let us assume that there is such a way of identifying the row and it is in an `id` column that you are not showing; then, from Oracle 12, you can use:

```sql
UPDATE table_name t
SET branch_name = ( SELECT branch_name
                    FROM   table_name m
                    WHERE  m.branch_id = t.branch_id
                    ORDER BY id ASC                   -- specify an order
                    FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY );
```

If you do not have a way of ordering the rows and want the `MIN`imum value as the "first" (which may not be the first row that you see on your display) then:

```sql
UPDATE table_name t
SET branch_name = ( SELECT MIN(branch_name)
                    FROM   table_name m
                    WHERE  m.branch_id = t.branch_id );
```

---

If you do not want to replace (`UPDATE`) the values in the table and only want to change what is being displayed then you can use:

```sql
SELECT branch_id,
       branch_loc,
       FIRST_VALUE(branch_name) OVER (PARTITION BY branch_id ORDER BY id) AS branch_name
FROM   table_name;
```

or, if you do not have a column that you can order by and want the minimum:

```sql
SELECT branch_id,
       branch_loc,
       MIN(branch_name) OVER (PARTITION BY branch_id) AS branch_name
FROM   table_name;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/iV3x9zyO)

Comment: Hi All thanks for ur response. How ever we should not update in the table . Just replace the value in the query and show the result

Comment: @Rock Updated with `SELECT` queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FIRST_VALUE` function along with `IGNORE NULLS` such as

```
SELECT branch_id, branch_loc,
       FIRST_VALUE(branch_name) IGNORE NULLS OVER (PARTITION BY branch_id) AS branch_name
  FROM t
```

through this no matter how the `branch_name` columns have been sorted per each `branch_id` value